# Restricting position of custom logos/images on quarto revealjs slides to be on the slides

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I'm trying to set up a template for lecture slides using revealjs in quarto. Specifically, I want a watermark on the lower right and a university logo on the top left. Since I'm using two logos I cannot only use the `logos:` argument in the YAML-header.

I've managed to include both logos by creating a separate html-file which I include in the yaml-header with `include-in-header: [test.html]` and then I specify the positions in the associated `.scss` file.

test.html looks like this:

```
  <img class="bottom-logo" src="lower_logo.png"/>
  <img class="top-logo" src="upper_logo.png"/>
```

and the associated `.scss` file like this:

```
.bottom-logo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.top-logo {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px;
    left: 30px;
    height: 125px;
}
```

This code successfully includes the logos at the lower right and top left positions, but the logos are outside the revealjs slides, so when I try to export the slides to PDF the logos are not included. I've tried adding .reveal and .reveal .slides as suggested in the quarto documentation, but this does not seem to work. Any suggestions on how to restrict the logos to be within the revealjs slides?

Answer (score 0):

what about combining logo from [`reveal-header`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/reveal-header) (places logo on top left) extension and footer? Example:

```
---
title: Example slide
format: 
  revealjs:
    footer: Content under {{< fa brands creative-commons >}}
    header-logo: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/RStudio_logo_flat.svg
filters:
  - reveal-header
---

<style>
.reveal .footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px -20px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
```

[image]

---

**Edit**: Larger Logo

```
---
title: Example slide
format: 
  revealjs:
    footer: Content under {{< fa brands creative-commons >}}
    logo: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/RStudio_logo_flat.svg

---

<style>
.reveal .footer {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px -20px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.reveal .slide-logo {
    z-index: 2;
    right: unset !important;
    height: unset !important;
    bottom: unset !important;
    width: 400px !important;
    max-width: unset !important;
    max-height: unset !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works but there seems to be a limit on the customization on the position for the top-left logo. I would like to make it slightly larger than what seems allowed and move it slightly more to the right. Tried a bunch of potions, but always seems to be overridden somewhere

Comment: Have you tried putting `!important` behind the modification such that it gets not overwritten?

Comment: Yes, for instance tried using `max-width: 400px !important` and `max-height: 400px !important`

Comment: I make an edit. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the lower right logo (the .slide-logo) but not for the header-logo where the problem was. I managed to solve the problem by digging into the extension css file and manually setting the max-width and max-height arguments in that css. I tried setting and unsetting this in my custom scss theme file, but it does not seem to respond to `unset !important`

Comment: I'm not well enough versed in html/css to figure out why this is the case